# QML is suddenly totally unresponsive to mouse and c++ program, linux mint platform

Tags: linux, qml, linux-mint, qqmlapplicationengine

After the QML suddenly failed, I reloaded the complete Qt system.  It still will not respond to mouse inputs to any button, even the 'x' close button. The C++ interface outputs are not displayed.  If the program is started from the debugger it hangs loading the thread in app.exe.  This is a large program that has been working.  A previous version saved to the desktop now displays the same symptoms.

Linux Mint 20.3, QtCreator 11.0.2, Qt 6.4.3

Tried deleting and reinstalling the entire Qt platform.  This made no difference.

Comment: Is it only your app that doesn't work? Are you able to build and run other Qt apps?

Comment: Further checks... yeah small projects build and run.  I am beginning to think it may be either a system resource problem or one of the libraries used by the large project.  Nothing really changed in the project worked to the project is totally unresponsive.  Trying to run debug cannot even use mouse on qtcreator.

Comment: I misspoke.  The qtcreator is a shadow window over the real qtcreator.  Apparently the app has started just enough to create some form of window framework that picked up the qtcreator display as its own background ??

Comment: Are there any errors on the console? In my apps, often if I make a mistake in my code somewhere that causes the QML to fail to load, I get just a transparent window popup. But in that case I usually get errors on the console telling me what went wrong.

Comment: If this has recently started to break, you should consider reviewing your code for recent commits/breaking changes. Something like `git bisect` may assist you in this type of explorative troubleshooting.

Comment: The problem turned out to be the event loop blocked before the app could complete loading.  The transparent window completely overlaid QtCreator so it made it appear QtCreator was unresponsive.  Turned out I could move the transparent window and reach QtCreator and break on the program.   The root of the problem was an unexpected response from an RS-486 card, never completing data transfer.